# Create a system to add product tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am developing my own E-Commerce. I want to create an interface like the one shown in the image to add tags to a product. I want that when the tag is added, it is displayed as the image.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thjr3.png)

Please, could you tell me some way to try to solve this problem? Some tips or examples to achieve it with HTML or Javascript.

Comment: Hi Emili, welcome to SO. The reason this question is being down-voted is that you haven't shown what you've already tried so far or if you have tried this for yourself at all.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: That's ok, just wanted to give you feedback so that you can improve your questions going forward. You can read about how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need but it's something you can start from.

```js
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tags");
  var li = document.createElement("LI");
  var a = document.createElement("A");
  var temp=x.appendChild(li);
  temp=temp.appendChild(a);
  temp.innerHTML=document.getElementById("name").value;
  temp.setAttribute("class","tag");
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px/1.5 'PT Sans', serif;
  margin: 25px;
}

.tags {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0;
}

.tags li {
  float: left; 
}

.tag {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tag::before {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  top: 10px;
}

.tag::after {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tag:hover {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}

.tag:hover::after {
   border-left-color: crimson; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tags</h1>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
<button id="add">Add</button>


<h2>Example</h2>
<ul id="tags" class="tags">
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much!